# Complete list of FontAwesome Icons for Select

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, font-awesome-4

I'm attempting to populate a Select Dropdown with a complete (v 4.2) list of FontAwesome Icons. The closest list I could find is [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Font-Awesome-HTML-Dropdown-Select-List), but it's grossly out of date. Does anyone have a list they can refer me to?

Comment: Um... Are you looking for this: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/ ?

Comment: As great of a resource as that is (I use it often), no. I'm essentially looking for

`<optgroup label="Web Application Icons">
      <option value="adjust">adjust</option>
      <option value="asterisk">asterisk</option>
      <option value="ban-circle">ban-circle</option>
<!-- etc... -->`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This URL: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/ contains the list of all the icons. While it's not in the format you've described, we can use some jquery to transform it to what you want:

```
$.map($("h2").map(function(){ 
    var a = $(this).nextAll(".row:first").find("a").map(function(){ 
        return $(this).attr('href').split("/").slice(-1)[0]; 
    }); 
    return {title: $(this).html(), options: a} 
}), function(object){ return "<optgroup label='"+object.title+"'>"+$.map($.unique(object.options), function(option){ return "<option>"+option+"</option>"; }).join("")+"</optgroup>"; }).join("");
```

Which generates this list: http://pastebin.com/NQ1S7RJF

(Please bear in mind that it's a list of unique icons - it won't contain, for example: `file-sound-o`, because it's an alias for `file-audio-o`)